# Required a Distributed cache for Java and .NET

Tags: java, asp.net, caching, distributed

I am looking for a distributed caching solution which can help in sharing sessions between .Net and Java Applications. I want high performance and yet no extra codings. Currently I was using “ j-memcached”. But it has slow response time and performance issues. Can someone help me with the problem

Comment: j-memcached claim to be server side for memcached protocol. So first solution will be switch to any other memcached.   did you see if your problems with some other part of code?

Answer (score 2):

If commercial solutions are acceptable, there are both [Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html) (from Oracle) and [GigaSpaces XAP](http://www.gigaspaces.com/xap), both of which provide data interoperability (and process interop, in GigaSpaces' case) between Java and .Net.

For a video of the GigaSpaces interop, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTRvuE8kQs0 .

Answer (score 1):

When I came in distributed cache world I first started with AppFabric but that wasn't much reliable and it offers limited features then the other better solution that I found was NCache (an in-memory [Distributed Cache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/index.html) ) and I never had to face any performance issues with it moreover it is supported in .Net and Java without any code change on windows and Linux platform as well. So my first recommendation would be NCache and then AppFabric (but only if anyone can compromise on limited functionality and performance).

Answer (score 0):

How about [MemCached](http://memcached.org/)? I don't have first hand experience but it does list some big names as its users! From .NET side, there is [Session State provider](http://memcachedproviders.codeplex.com/) for memcached.

Comment: Isn't j-memcached a client for memcached? If so, he's already using memcached.

Comment: we've already tried memcached but it has some limitations that's why it is giving us the desired results. in my personal experience, its good for smaller web farm but not for a larger web garden.